# Forcing a UITextView to wrap properly

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, uilabel, uitextview

I have a UITextView with the following text:

```
textView.text = @"aaa a a a a a  a zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz";
```

When I run it in the CGRect that I provided it goes like this:

```
aaa a a a a a  a 
zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz <-text view width ends here
zzzzzzz
```

But I want it to work like a UILabel with numberOfLines = 0, which gives me this:

```
aaa a a a a a  a zzzzzz <-text view width ends here
zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz <-text view width ends here
z
```

With iOS 6, UILineBreakMode was deprecated. How do I achieve this now?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`UILineBreakMode` is deprecated but not `NSLineBreakMode`.
You should use `NSLineBreakByCharWrapping` meaning that the word'll be cut after a character.

```
textView.textContainer.lineBreakMode = .byCharWrapping
```

Comment: hmmm but do UITextView have a line break mode?

Comment: self.textView.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByCharWrapping;

Comment: @chris `textview.textContainer.lineBreakMode` I guess :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do it in Objective-C

```
textView.textContainer.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByCharWrapping;
```